# How to add extra options to iOS Share Sheet like Safari does

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to reproduce what Apple does with Safari, where there is a sharing button that allows to share the current page but also provides some extra (and internal) options to do with the page.

For example, we are given options to Add to the reading list, add as bookmark, etc.

[image]

These options are exclusive to Safari, as they are not part of the default Share Sheet. How can I hide some of my own app's functionality under a Share Sheet like that?

I did some research and I only found out about custom activities which (as I understand) are the squared buttons that are in the second row of the share sheet (partially hidden in my screenshot).

I also found out about extensions, but I don't think that helps my case, as that allows to customize the share sheet globally for every app, and I need to add options in my app's runtime.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you initialise a share sheet (aka `UIActivityController`), you are asked for an array of `applicationActivities`, that is where your custom internal/share actions will go.

You should just subclass `UIActivity`, and override the required members as specified by the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivity):

> - `activityType`
> - `activityTitle`
> - `activityImage`
> - `canPerform(withActivityItems:)`
> - `prepare(withActivityItems:)`
> - `activityCategory`

To make your `UIActivity` appear as a menu button at the bottom of the share sheet, make sure you return `.action` for `activityCategory`. If you return `.share`, it will appear as a square button at the top.

Example:

```
// dummy implementation
class Foo: UIActivity {
    override var activityTitle: String? { "Foo" }
    override var activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType? { UIActivity.ActivityType("Foo") }
    override var activityImage: UIImage? { UIImage(systemName: "doc.on.doc.fill") }
    override func canPerform(withActivityItems activityItems: [Any]) -> Bool {
        true
    }
    override class var activityCategory: UIActivity.Category { .action }
    override func prepare(withActivityItems activityItems: [Any]) {
        print("Preparing Foo!")
    }
    override func perform() {
        print("Performed Foo!")
    }
}

...

let shareSheet = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [stuffToShare], applicationActivities: [Foo()])
```

Output:

[image]

If I use `.share` instead:

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer, is there any way to leverage this in SwiftUI land? ShareLink doesn’t really have a lot of flexibility and a UIViewControllerRepresentable wrapped UIActivityController looses the interactive dismiss gesture.

Comment: @ShawnThroop No, as far as I know. I think you can still have an interactive dismiss if you write the share button in UIKit too, but yeah, I agree it's not beautiful.

Comment: Sigh. Thanks for the confirmation, UIKit is the way to go but I wish it wasn’t at this point. As always, I’ll be hoping for some back-deployed ShareLink additions at the next WWDC